# How do I get the count of a Viewbag without using model.Count

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, viewbag

How do I get the count of items from a lambda expression in a veiwbag ?

I dont want to use model.count() as I have a model directive for other models and this is for something different

here is my code

```
            var Count = _context.Users_Accounts_Address
         .Where(c => c.Email == user)
         .Select(c =>  c.Post_Code + " " +c.AddressType );

 ViewBag.ReturnCount = Count.CountAsync();
```

and my view I put

```
@ViewBag.ReturnCount
```

At runtime However I get back

```
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Int32]
```

Comment: @freedomn-m is right (should put as answer instead of comment), you're getting a task back because you are using the `async` method. Alternatively, you could `await Count.CountAsync()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.CountAsync()` you get back an asynchronous `Task<T>` object (in this case `T` is an `int` as that's the return type of the non-async `.Count()` method.

You should use either:

```
ViewBag.ReturnCount = Count.Count();
```

or

```
ViewBag.ReturnCount = await Count.CountAsync();
```

(if your controller is async)

Comment: I see, I forgot to add the await keyword. thanks a lot